# How to get current id of inserted object and deliver to another controller

Tags: entity-framework, indexing, view, relational-database

I have 2 view's: Auction and Item.
In a first view I create Auction:
 [image]

After clicked 'Create' it's redirect to Item View:
[image]

How to send current id of inserted auction to do relation between auction and item. The finish result should be that actual item details has info about auction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you insert entity, DbContext assigns created entity id. Then you can pass that id to your second page in querystring parameter.

```
_context.Auctions.Add(auction);
_context.SaveChanges(); 
// auction.Id now contains database generated id
// pass it to second page, like this in asp.net mvc
return RedirectToAction("SecondPage", new { auctionId = auction.Id });
```

Second page:

```
public ActionResult SecondPage(int auctionId) { ... }
```